# Opencover installation

Tags: c#, windows, dll, regsvr32, opencover

I am trying to use Opencover in win xp system (for a C# package test coverage) and I get a strange error while trying to register the Opencover.profiler.dll to regsvr32.exe manually. I get an error telling "Load library ("dll name") failed" with error level 9009. (I did a echo %ERRORLEVEL% after trying to register the dll)

Google search suggests this error code has something to do with xcopy. But I am unsure why this occurs while registering dll.

I know that there is a register:user switch to do this. But I tried the above way to know why the registration failed.

The Opencover version for which i get the above error is 2.0.802. In the same system, I am able to register the 4.0.804 dll without any issues. And the version 2.0.802 dll works with my other XP system.

May I know what could be the issue with this? I hope it is something to do Windows and not Opencover

Answer (score 1):

Early versions of OpenCover where dependent on "VC++ redistributables" which if they are missing may account for you registration failure.

Later versions are now statically linked to avoid such scenarios.

https://github.com/sawilde/opencover/issues/52